# Unit Hurwitz quaternions forms a group

Tags: group-theory, quaternions

Define Hurwitz quaternions by $\mathbb{H}=\left\{a+bi+cj+dk\in \mathbb {H} \mid a,b,c,d\in \mathbb {Z} \;{\mbox{ or }}\,a,b,c,d\in \mathbb {Z} +{\tfrac {1}{2}}\right\}.$

My question is, does unit quaternions (i.e. those quaternions $q\in\mathbb{H}$, for which $\left|q\right|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}=1$) forms a group?
There are $24$ unit quaternions: $\pm1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k, \frac{1}{2}\left(\pm 1\pm i\pm j\pm k\right).$

How to show for example associativity? I mean, I could check all combinations of elements or point to fact that Hurwitz quaternions satisfy associativity too, but I don't think it is the best way to go.

Comment: quaternions satisfy associativity in general. So any subset will as well.

Comment: Why not do a subgroup test instead?

Comment: I don't know why you would ever want to explicitly check that the operation in a subgroup is associative; closure and the existence of inverses are what you need to check.  You don't say whether you mean an additive or multiplicative group.  For addition, it's obviously not closed.  For multiplication, if I recall correctly, you don't have inverses, but I am be wrong.

Comment: You must first check that the product of any two units is unit.

Comment: As @RobertTheTutor said, after you show this set is closed under multiplication, it inherits associativity automatically from quaternion multiplication. Of course, then there's the issue of having verified quaternion multiplication was associative to begin with...

Comment: At any rate, for closure, you want to do what @kabenyuk said: show the product of unit Hurwtiz quaternions are still unit Hurwitz quaternions.

Comment: @ChubbyChef This is viable if you know the unit Hurwitz quaternions are a subset of a group to begin with. That means OP would have had to already know e.g. $S^3$ was already a group (which they may or may not, I don't know).

Comment: @saulspatz You are wrong: the unit Hurwitz quaternions are closed under multiplicative inverses.

Comment: @runway44 Not for the first or last time.  I'll have to look at them again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Hurwitz quaternions, which is also known as the binary tetrahedral group $2T$ (and I will explain this at the end), inherit associativity from quaternion multiplication itself. If $(X,\cdot)$ is any set with an associative operation $\cdot$, and $Y\subseteq X$ is a subset closed under that operation, then $(Y,\cdot)$ itself is an algebraic structure with an associative operation! But it still means you have to show $2T$ is closed under multiplication.

Of course, this also means you should have verified quaternion multiplication on $\mathbb{H}$ was associative to begin with. You can do this by first showing it is associative for certain expressions involving basis elements $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$ (by symmetry you don't have to check all possible expressions, only some of them), then argue it works for all quaternions since $\{1,\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}\}$ spans them. Or, if you instead define quaternion multiplication using dot products and cross products (this is a more "coordinate-free" and "intrinsic" definition), you would check associativity using dot product and cross product identities and geometry. (Fun!)

Now you want to show $2T$ is closed under multiplication. For this, I recommend splitting this into two facts: the Hurwitz integers are closed under multiplication, and the unit quaternions aka versors (which form a three-sphere $S^3$, just as unit complex numbers aka phasors form a unit circle $S^1$) are closed under multiplication. We can show $S^3$ is a group by using the fact that the quaternion norm is multiplicative. We can show the Hurwitz quaternions are closed under multiplication by checking the numerators of the components mod $2$ are $1+1+1+1$. (Or, arguably you could show Hurwitz quaternions are closed under multiplication by showing $2T$ is a group and a $\mathbb{Z}$-spanning set.)

Indeed, we can determine $2T$'s structure. If you denote the $3$rd root of unity

$$ \omega=\tfrac{1}{2}\big(-1+\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k}\big)=\exp\big(\tfrac{2\pi}{3}(\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k})\big), $$

you can verify $2T=Q_8\sqcup Q_8\omega\sqcup Q_8\omega^2$, where $Q_8=\{\pm1,\pm\mathbf{i},\pm\mathbf{j},\pm\mathbf{k}\}$ is the so-called "quaternion group" (I used to refer to $2T$ by $Q_{24}$, fun fact). Indeed, by checking $\omega Q_8\omega^{-1}= Q_8$ (which requires merely checking for $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$ since $\pm1$ are evidently central) we see $Q_8$ is normal, so indeed $2T=Q_8\rtimes C_3$ is a semidirect product, where $C_3=\langle\omega\rangle$ is cyclic of order $3$.

It's also fun to note that while the Lipschitz integers $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}]$ give you a tiling of tesseracts, the diagonals of the hypercubes have length $\sqrt{1+1+1+1}=2$, so if we situate spheres of diameter $1$ at integer coordinates there is exactly enough room to fit more spheres at half-integer coordinates. In other words, this is how a 4D grocer would stack 4D oranges.

The unit quaternions $S^3$ can be used to model 3D rotations. Quaternions have polar forms, and if we have a versor $p=\exp(\theta\mathbf{v})$, then $p\mathbf{x}p^{-1}$ as a function of 3D vectors $\mathbf{x}$ is a rotation around the axis $\mathbf{v}$ by an angle $2\theta$. Indeed, there is a $2$-to-$1$ onto group homomorphism $S^3\to\mathrm{SO}(3)$ (the latter being the group of $3\times3$ rotation matrices) with kernel $S^0=\{\pm1\}$ (the unit reals). The regular tetrahedron has a orientation-preserving symmetry group of order $12$ called $T\cong A_4$ achieving all even permutations of its four vertices. (The full symmetry group includes reflections and is isomorphic to $S_4$, achieving all permutations of the four vertices.) The preimage of $T$ under the spin homomorphism $S^3\to\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is the so-called binary tetrahedral group $2T$ of order $24$. We can pick a cube, centered at $\mathbf{0}$ of side-length $2$ with vertices $\pm\mathbf{i}\pm\mathbf{j}\pm\mathbf{k}$, and there is an inscribed tetrahedron with alternative vertices of evenly-many minus signs. The corresponding unit quaternions in $2T$ are precisely the unit Hurwitz quaternions!